# How to reverse (or, mirror) texts in latex?

Tags: text-decorations

I wanna know if there's any way to reverse texts in latex so that I can use it to print on tracing paper for press printing.

For good understanding my question, please see the graphic have I attached with.

[image]

Comment: Image source: https://appuals.com/mirror-text-word/

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Load `\usepackage{graphicx}` then `\reflectbox{Flip me!}`.

Comment: yeah! both two comments are helpful for me.